# Matching axes scales

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have 3D data plotted using the 'plot3' function. I would like to constrain the Y and Z axes such that they are equal in scale. The X axis should be automatically scaled as usual.

I know from [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html) that I can make the X axis be the only one to be automatically scaled by using the command:

```
axis 'auto x';
```

However, this causes the Y and Z axes to be plotted from 0 to 1 only; my data often exceeds this in all axes. What I'm looking for is a plot which contains all the data in a single view, but with the smallest of the Y or Z axes scaled down so that the Y and Z axes are equivalent in scale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `daspect`.

```
plot3(5*rand(10,1),10*rand(10,1),rand(10,1))

tmpAspect=daspect();
daspect(tmpAspect([1 2 2]))
```

`daspect()` returns the current aspect ratio as produced by axis 'auto'.

`daspect(tmpAspect([1 2 2]))` then enforces that y and z have the same scale.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
axis equal
```

or even

```
axis tight
axis equal
```

both *after* the plot has been drawn.

Is this what you mean?

Type `help axis` at the Matlab command prompt for more capabilities of the `axis` function.

Comment: Yes - "axis equal" does the job, except I only want this to apply to the Y and Z axes; the X axis should remain as it is